# Can you run EJB 2.1 beans in OSGi?

Tags: jboss, osgi, ejb-2.x, stateless-session-bean, entity-bean

I have a J2EE 1.3 app that uses EJB 2.1 session and entity beans. Currently this app runs as an EAR file on JBoss. I'd like to switch to the SpringSource dm Application Server because of all the benefits that OSGi provides.

Does anyone know if there's an OSGi bundle that can act as an EJB container? Can [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/) do this?

Answer (score 2):

hope that it could help you:

http://darrylnelson.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/openejb-in-felix/#

It helps me a lot :-)